# swapping two integers without creating a third overflow

Tags: c, swap

I am trying to write a swapping function without using a tmp in C, here's what I'm using:

```
void swap(int *a, int* b) {
    *a += *b;
    *b = *a - *b;
    *a -= *b;
}
```

Now one problem (or so I thought) with this is that we may overflow if `*a + * b > INT_MAX`. What's confusing is that it actually works just fine even with edge cases.. can someone explain why??

Here are some of the test cases I used:

```
int main() {
    int t1Swap[] = {INT_MAX, 1};
    int t2Swap[] = {INT_MAX, INT_MIN};
    int t3Swap[] = {INT_MAX, INT_MAX-1000};
    int t4Swap[] = {INT_MIN, INT_MIN+1000};
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: *I am trying to write a swapping function without using a tmp*  Why?  If it's not just as an exercise to learn how to do it, anything you write will probably be slower than what any halfway decent compiler does with the swap with a temp.  Micro-optimizing code like this in the absence of any measured performance and profiling data is usually a waste of a programmer's time.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Great point.

Comment: Overflow is *undefined behaviour*; anything is possible, and it seems that "anything" on your current platform is the result you wanted.

Comment: Try test case `int x = 42; swap(&x, &x);`

Answer (score 5):

Signed integer overflow is undefined behavior, so it may or may not work depending on your particular system and compiler. To avoid this undefined behavior, use the bitwise XOR operator instead of addition and subtraction to swap variables without introducing a `temp`:

```
a=a^b;
b=a^b;
a=a^b;
```

Comment: Looks good but does not show how to use in it `swap(int *a, int* b)`.  With `(*a) = (*a) ^ (*b);...` code will fail to function as hoped when `a==b`.

Answer (score 2):

You can user XOR like this;

```
void swap(int *a, int *b)
{
    if (*a != *b)
    {
        *a^=*b;
        *b^=*a;
        *a^=*b;
    }
}
```

Comment: It's just a logical operation so there is no chance for overflow.

Comment: That's undefined behaviour - multiple stores to `a` without an intervening sequence point.  Write it as two statements.

Comment: Code fails to function as desired when `a==b`.

Answer (score 2):

Even though integer overflow is technically undefined behavior, it usually wraps around to INT_MIN. In that case, your arithmetic implementation works (but it's not portable).

Answer (score 2):

if you goalr is to generate as fast as possible code (or to save some memory) the tricky XOR or add methods are not the best choice:

Consider:

```
void swap1(int *a, int *b)
{
    *a=*a^*b;
    *b=*a^*b;
    *a=*a^*b;
}

void swap2(int *a, int *b)
{
    int c = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = c;
}
```

and the resulting code:
X86

```
swap1:
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rdi]
        xor     eax, DWORD PTR [rsi]
        mov     DWORD PTR [rdi], eax
        xor     eax, DWORD PTR [rsi]
        mov     DWORD PTR [rsi], eax
        xor     DWORD PTR [rdi], eax
        ret
swap2:
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rdi]
        mov     edx, DWORD PTR [rsi]
        mov     DWORD PTR [rdi], edx
        mov     DWORD PTR [rsi], eax
        ret
```

So without the temp variable you do not save any memory but make the algorithm slower. What is the point?

Comment: It seems that you *did* save one register (`edx`) in `swap1`.  I agree it's unlikely to be a net win, even if you spill it and need to restore afterwards.

Comment: Let me re-phrase.  I said that `swap1` uses only `eax`, whereas `swap2` uses `eax` and `edx`.  If your main criterion is use of temporaries, then `swap1` is the better choice.  But neither of us believe that's a good criterion.  `:-)`

Comment: `swap2(int *a, int *b)` an advantage over `swap1(int *a, int *b)`.  When `a==b`, `swap2()` works as hoped.  `swap1()` does not.  P__J__, good that you showed the superior `swap2()` alternative - both in tighter code and proper unsurprising functionality.